# Analyzer for "JavaSonarQube" and "Java Common Sonarqube"

Tags: java, netbeans, sonarqube, rules, analyzer

I would like do locally the code analysis that Sonar does on the server.

Concerning the rules for PMD, Findbugs and Checkstyle I have no problems to download them and import in Netbeans with the appropriate plugins.

My question concerns two additional sets of rules that I find in sonar called "JavaSonarQube"and "Java Common Sonarqube". At what kind of analyzer them refers to and how can I import and run them in NetBeans?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't, not directly in Netbeans. [SonarLint](http://www.sonarlint.org/) is available for IntelliJ IDEA, and Eclipse to run those rules locally, but not for NetBeans. You could, however, run a [Preview analysis](http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Getting+Issues+Report+in+Preview+Mode).

Comment: What SonarLint exactly does? I noticed that netbeans has a plugin called Radar, maybe has the same purpose?